# How to use RED5 to enable live broadcast from a file?

Tags: red5, broadcast

Is it possible to set up RED5 in a way where different users logging in at different times will be seeing the stream from an elapsed time period since the broadcast started? Say, my prescheduled broadcast starts at 10:00AM, is it possible for the user logging in at 10:05AM to start viewing the stream from the 5 minutes mark from video start? Much like a prerecorded online radio.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the examples:
    http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/java/example/trunk
    http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/flash/trunk/

You might be able to use these for what you need:
    http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/java/example/trunk/oflaDemo/
    http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/flash/trunk/simpleSubscriber.fla
    http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/flash/trunk/simpleBroadcaster.fla

These do no create a recorded just the live feed, like radio.